# When is it worth competing to farm fields?

Tags: carcassonne

Is it worth fighting for my opponents' fields when there are still 60+ tiles in the game and I have no fields, or is it too soon?

I usually lose games because of fields and not knowing when to lay my meeples.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

If you're losing because your opponent is scoring fields and you aren't, then yes, you will have to fight for those fields.  The tricky thing with fields is that you have to commit to them before you know what they will be worth, so try to estimate in your own mind what a field will be worth at the end of the game and factor it in your calculations.

Watch out for the "cloister with a road" tile coming out early, this will cause there to be one large field at the end and a big fight for the farming.

If fighting for the farming doesn't suit your playing style then try to play in a way that prevents large fields forming -- use road junctions to break them up and try to stop people creating loops with roads.  Then build your cities away from the big fields.  Additionally, opponents who commit heavily to farming early on will be short of meeples during the game and you should be able to bully them during the game by playing tiles to slow or prevent them from completing their cities/roads/cloisters, or joining your meeples into their cities generally obstructing their completion.  With your spare meeples you should be able complete lots of features and rack up the points.

Answer (score 2):

That really depends on what expansions you play and on the individual game. Sometimes you can tell very early that a field is going to be very important, when you have lots of tiny cities from the very beginning on that field. In those cases, fighting for that field can become an early priority.

On the other hand, when you're playing with the Princess and Dragon expansion, there is a good chance that you can kick a competitor out of a field (or he does it to you), so you may not have to go all too aggressive on the fields.

All in all, there is no general answer. Try to play consciously, play a lot, and eventually you'll get a good feeling for when to fight for a field and when not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fighting for fields in an important part of the game and you should devote a percentage of your meeples to this task.  Using 2 meeples at minimum for fields will help you diversify your strategy.  Be sure to wait until about a third of the  game to lay your pieces down in fields so that you can get an idea of what your opponents' strategies are before committing too early or too late.

Knowing that you have set aside pieces for this strategy will keep you from feeling pressured about laying those meeples down or not.  It will also distract from other strategies you may be pursuing, like building cities or roads.  I would especially keep one or two meeples ready for fields as the game gets close to finishing as those may be the ones that secure the fields for you as your opponents scramble to complete cities and roads.